# Is there a continuous surjective map from $S^1$ to $S^n$ ($n \geq 2$)?

Tags: general-topology

For integer $n \geq 1$, let $S^n$ be the $n$-dimensional sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

I wonder if there exists a continuous surjective map from $S^1$ to $S^n$ ($n \geq 2$).

I derived that if there is such a map, it is not injective because a continuous bijective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is homeomorphism. However, I do not have any idea to proceed.

Would you tell me any ideas or hints?

Thank you.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Why is there no continuous surjecive map from a bounded line to a disk?

Comment: Google "space filling curve".

Comment: @AdamRubinson: The whole idea of a space-filling curve is that it is a continuous surjective map from a closed interval (is that what you mean by "bounded line"?) to a closed disk.

Comment: Apologies for my comments - I was guessing. For some reason, I thought a space-filling curve doesn't actually fill up a closed disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it is easy to have a continuous surjective map from $S^1$ to $[0,1]$ (just "squish the circle flat").

Now consider a [space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) $(x(t), y(t))$ that is a continuous surjective map from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^2$.

By iterating, we can get a continuous surjective map $(x(x(t)), y(x(t)), y(t))$ from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]^3$, or similarly to any $[0,1]^n$.

It is easy to find a continuous surjective map from $[0,1]^n$ to $S^n$ (e.g. by mapping the boundary of $[0,1]^n$ to a single point).

Composing these all, we have a continuous surjective map from $S^1$ to $S^n$.